# How to update/delete array in post meta value?

Tags: post-meta

I using post meta like..

```
$meta = get_post_meta(99,'_mymeta',true);
$value = $meta['somekey'];
echo $value;
```

But how to update `$meta['somekey']` to some another value ?

How to use [update_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) to update sub meta key ?(Idk, How ppl call)

```
update_post_meta(99, '_mymeta["somekey"]', 'myAnotherValue');
```

?????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To update post meta that are an array: you have to fetch the original values, change the value you need and update it again. For example

```
$list_of_values = get_post_meta($post_id, '_list_values', true);
if(!empty($list_of_values)) {
    $list_of_values["some_prop"] = "new value";
}
update_post_meta($post_id, '_list_values', $list_of_values);
```

Comment: Thanks so much , What about deleting an array ?

Comment: @l2aelba: you can either set the value to empty, or do unset($list_of_values["element_to_delete"]);